Convergence of $\sum^{\infty }_{n=0} |a_{n}-b_{n}|$ from convergence of $\sum^{\infty }_{n=0} |a_{n}|$ and $\sum^{\infty }_{n=0} |b_{n}|$
Exercise 12.1.15 of Tao's Analysis II book asks the reader to show that the function $d:X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \left\{ \infty \right\}  $ defined by $d\left( a_{n},b_{n}\right)  =\sum^{\infty }_{{}n=0} \left| a_{n}-b_{n}\right|  $ forms a metric over the space $$ X=\left\{ a_{n}\mid \sum^{\infty }_{n=0} |a_{n}|<\infty \right\}  $$
of real sequences whose infinite series converge absolutely.
From my understanding, we're supposed to first show that $d$ actually maps every pair of sequences $a_{n},b_{n}\in X$ to a finite real number, or that the series $\sum^{\infty }_{n=0} |a_{n}-b_{n}|$ converges. Taking $\sum^{\infty }_{n=0} \left| a_{n}\right|  =A$ and $\sum^{\infty }_{n=0} |b_{n}|=B$, my initial approach was to first apply the reverse triangle inequality to obtain the upper bound $$\left| \sum^{m}_{n=0} |a_{n}-b_{n}|-|A-B|\right|  \leq \left| \sum^{m}_{n=0} |a_{n}-b_{n}|-\left( A-B\right)  \right| $$
From there, I figured that we could eventually obtain the upper bound $$\cdots \leq \left| \sum^{m}_{n=0} |a_{n}|-\sum^{m}_{n=0} |b_{n}|-\left( A-B\right)  \right|  \leq \left| \sum^{m}_{n=0} |a_{n}|-A\right|  +\left| \sum^{m}_{n=0} |b_{n}|-B\right|  $$
from which convergence would follow, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about this. I also considered the comparison test but I can't figure out how to estimate $\left| a_{n}-b_{n}\right|  $ from above in terms of $\left| a_{n}\right|  $ and $\left| b_{n}\right|  $. Any advice on how to proceed?

If you only want to prove the convergence you can use the triangle inequality on $|a_n-b_n|$

What does make a function $d:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ a metric, when $X\neq\varnothing$?
Here we provide its explicit definition. Given $\{a,b,c\}\subseteq X$, one must have

$d_{X}(a,b)\geq 0$ and $d_{X}(a,b) = 0$ iff $a = b$.
$d_{X}(a,b) = d_{X}(b,a)$
$d_{X}(a,c) \leq d_{X}(a,b) + d_{X}(b,c)$

The first property $d_{X}(a,b)\geq 0$ to be satisfied results from the fact that $|a_{n} - b_{n}|\geq 0$.
The second property to be satisfied results from the fact that a sum of nonnegative terms equals zero iff each of its terms are equal to zero. That is to say, $d_{X}(a,b) = 0$ iff $a_{k} = b_{k}$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$, which is equivalent to claim that $a = b$.
The third property to be satisfied results from the fact that $|a_{n} - b_{n}| = |b_{n} - a_{n}|$.
Finally, the fourth property to be satisfied results from the triangle inequality of the absolute value:
\begin{align*}
d_{X}(a,c) & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|a_{k} - c_{k}|\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|(a_{k} - b_{k}) + (b_{k} - c_{k})|\\
& \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\left(|a_{k} - b_{k}| + |b_{k} - c_{k}|\right)\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|a_{k} - b_{k}| + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}|b_{k} - c_{k}|\right)\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|a_{k} - b_{k}| + \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|b_{k} - c_{k}|\\
& = d_{X}(a,b) + d_{X}(b,c).
\end{align*}
